# Изменение размера UserControl за границы. WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, usercontrol

Как сделать чтобы пользователь внутри главного окна мог изменять размеры `UserControl` за границы? Т.к настройки для `UserControl` нет, но для окна есть.

Comment: Ваш вопрос не понятен, попробуйте переформулировать.

Comment: @aepot А чего тут может быть не понятного? Есть `UserControl` внутри окна, надо сделать возможность изменять размер при растягивание его границ. Вот только автор не услышал походу то, что я написал ранее - окно внутри окна, это MDI и есть кучи готовых решений, которые из коробки сделают то, что надо. Не изобретайте велосипед!

Comment: А, MDI, так понятно.